# Explain the reason of a test restart in bazel

Tags: bazel

I have a test that restarts every time without any change in the code.
I use

`bazel test --explain ~/bazel-explain.log --verbose_explanations <test-target-name>`

to start the test.

```
Build options: <truncated>
Executing action 'BazelWorkspaceStatusAction stable-status.txt': unconditional execution is requested.
Executing action 'FileWrite build-info-volatile.h': unconditional execution is requested.
Executing action 'Testing <test-name>': One of the files has changed.
```

So the only useful information here is "One of the files has changed".

1. How to understand what file specifically has changed?
2. What does "file changed" means in bazel? Does bazel compare a hash of the file (or directory)? Does file change in terms of bazel if only the file's attributes are changed (such as the editing time)?

Comment: Can you give a minimal example that reproduces this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause. I use Zeppelin notebook as an external dependency. When Zeppelin runs, it changes the files inside its directory: it adds logs and modifies `interpreters.json` config. Every next run of the test the `zeppelin` directory is different from the previous snapshot. That's why bazel restarts the test every time.

When I remove the logs and revert the changes in the `interpreters.json` file, bazel does not restart the test. Now I will try to find out how to configure Zeppelin to use another directory for the files changing in run-time.

Unfortunately, I have not found bazel's tools or options that would help me to find the cause of the issue. I had to manually diff the `zeppelin` directory's snapshots.